# Angular 4 Auth0 Distinct Sign in and Sign up

Tags: angular, registration, auth0, sign, login-script

I'm trying to develop an app in angular4 using Auth0.
I would like to distinct the sign up and sign in process but I don't know how to do it. 
For exemple, after the registration, I would like to complete a field i,n the database but not after the sign in.

The problem is to open the lock, the only one function i have is :

```
public login(): void {
 this.auth0.authorize();
}
```

I agree, this open the lock but does not make a distinction between sign in and up.

Thank's

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User signup event in Auth0 Lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250292/user-signup-event-in-auth0-lock)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the Lock github README - you have various [show options](https://github.com/auth0/lock#showoptions) for controlling which Lock Views to display (login, signup only etc).